# LESS: quick way to not override conflictual rules on rounded corners to first and last item of a list

Tags: less, mixins

I have a link-bar with max 4 items in it, but in some cases could be reduced to only 1 item.

*I want rounded corners on left and right side of the bar only*, only first and last item has rounded corners.

Problem is when there is only 1 item, because with only a general call without `@side` parameter, `&:last-of-type` rule will obviously override `&:first-of-type one`.

How to optimize the following LESS Conditional Mixin?

```
.rounded_corners (@radius:5px, @side:all)
{
          border-radius:@radius;
}

.rounded_corners (@radius:5px, @side:all) when (@side = right)
{         
             border-top-right-radius:@radius;
          border-bottom-right-radius:@radius;
}

.rounded_corners (@radius:5px, @side:all) when (@side = left)
{
             border-top-left-radius:@radius;
          border-bottom-left-radius:@radius;
}
```

Called by:

```
&:first-of-type
{
  .rounded_corners(5px, left);
}

&:last-of-type
{
  .rounded_corners(5px, right);
}
```

**Is there a smarter and more compact way to achieve this purpose?**

Thank you.

P.S.: obviously vendor-prefixes are missing to simplify code, but their necessity highlights importance of a more compact solution in order to save code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for more expert answers, I personally developed this one:

```
.rounded_corners (@radius:5px, @side:all) when (@side = all)
{
  border-radius:@radius;
}

.rounded_corners (@radius:5px, @side:all) when not (@side = all)
{         
  border-top-@{side}-radius:@radius;
  border-bottom-@{side}-radius:@radius;
}
```

---

```
&:first-of-type
{
  .rounded_corners(5px, left);
}

&:last-of-type
{
  .rounded_corners(5px, right);
} 

div
{
  .rounded_corners();
}
```

That compile into this CSS:

```
:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
div {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Now mixins are only two, and sided corners are created using parameter values inside properties.

Any other better idea?

---

**UPDATE AFTER *Harry*'s suggestion:**

```
.rounded_corners (@radius:5px, @side:all) when (@side = all)
{
  border-radius:@radius;
}

.rounded_corners (@radius:5px, @side:all) when (@side = left), (@side = right)
{         
  border-top-@{side}-radius:@radius;
  border-bottom-@{side}-radius:@radius;
}
```

Comment: One suggestion I have is to use `.rounded_corners (@radius:5px, @side:all) when (@side = left), (@side = right)` instead of `not (@side = all)` because not all could even mean invalid values.

Comment: Regardless of mixins, is `div {border-radius: 5px}` necessary at all? If I understand it correctly both `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` styles apply to the only item and it already gets its four rounded corners -> [codepen](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/ipJCG).

Comment: You should be right only in case that there are always at least 2 items. But my solution is more general, allowing also that in some cases (number of items is dynamic and depends by DB) there could be also only one item in the list. :-)